# Redirecting users to custom page when email is verified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I was following a post on medium on how to do API email verification in Laravel 5.8 here https://medium.com/@pran.81/how-to-implement-laravels-must-verify-email-feature-in-the-api-registration-b531608ecb99

I tested it and it works perfectly but I was wondering how it would work when a  web or mobile application consumes the API. Here are my thoughts

1. Web or mobile user registers a new account by calling the route `Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register')` and the controller register method is this

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    // validate inputs

    // store new user & send verify email notification to user
    $user = User::create([
        'firstname' => $request->firstname,
        'lastname'  => $request->lastname,
        'username'  => $request->username,
        'password'  => bcrypt($request->password)
    ]);

    $user->sendApiEmailVerificationNotification();

    // assign access token to newly registered user

    // return access token & user data

}
```

2. User get an email with a `Verify Email Address` button

Now what should happen next? Should the user be redirected to the web app login page? If yes, how do I customise the redirect url? At the moment when I click on the verify email address button, a browser opens up and I get all the response on the browser page like this
[image: api endpoint response]

Answer (score 0):

Once the user clicks on Verify they are redirected to the path mentioned in

`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController`

Now if you want to change the redirect after verification you can change the below line of code with your route in `VerificationController`

`/**
* Where to redirect users after verification.
*
* @var string
*/
protected $redirectTo = '/home';`

Comment: I am not using the `VerificationController`, I have custom `ApiVerificationController` because the laravel project is API only. So will your solution work in an API environment or do I simple allow the web app deal with redirection after getting the response?

Comment: Okay so in your case redirect will not work you will need to send back json response and based on verification status you have to handle it on your client side

Comment: So I thought since the API is only supposed to return a json response. But do you think this is the right implementation with the response showing in the browser

Comment: the purpose of the verification URL is to just authenticate the user and nothing much

Comment: NO ! You never ever show the json response to the user everything happens in backend.

Comment: You need to handle it what should happen when user verified account using browser as mentioned in the answer either you can redirect it to somewhere or just exit with a message "Account Verified Successfully".  DO NOT SHOW RESPONSE IN BROWSER !!!

Comment: So how should i go about it? That's where i am confused

Comment: can you show me your code what happen after verification ?